# DLL load failed gpu

Tags: python, pytorch

I have an issue with PyTorch (GPU) when I try to import lib.

I use jupyterlab on a windows10.

This is my config :

```
*cudatoolkit=10.0.130=0
cudnn=7.6.4=cuda10.0_0
jupyterlab=3.1.7=pyhd3eb1b0_0
pip=21.2.4=py37haa95532_0
python=3.7.7=h81c818b_4
pytorch=1.2.0=py3.7_cuda100_cudnn7_1
scikit-learn=0.23.1=py37ha0ab79d_0
scipy=1.7.1=py37hbe87c03_2
torch=1.9.1=pypi_0
torchtext=0.10.1=pypi_0*
```

The error mentioned is

```
**---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\UTILIS~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1272/491987342.py in <module>
      9 import torch
     10 import torch.nn as nn
---> 11 import torchtext
     12 import torchtext.datasets
     13 import torchtext.vocab as vocab
_
~\.conda\envs\env_pytorch_gpu\lib\site-packages\torchtext\__init__.py in <module>
      3 from . import datasets
      4 from . import utils
----> 5 from . import vocab
      6 from . import legacy
      7 
~\.conda\envs\env_pytorch_gpu\lib\site-packages\torchtext\vocab.py in <module>
     11 from typing import Dict, List, Optional, Iterable
     12 from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
---> 13 from torchtext._torchtext import (
     14     Vocab as VocabPybind,
     15 )
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.**
```

I don't understand what happened. Could you help to fix this defect?

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of your torchtext version. Probably your torchtext version is old. You can try to install new version for torchtext, please:

```
pip install torchtext
```

Also you can control these requirement packages for torchtext [pypi torchtext](https://pypi.org/project/torchtext/0.11.0/)